# TLS Negotiation failed, the certificate doesn't match the host., code: 0

Tags: ssl, smtp

With Google changing their TLS strictness a few days ago, I just want to share the solution that works for me.

This [forum post was the answer](https://forum.webseodesigners.com/web-design-seo-and-hosting-f16/solved-tls-negotiation-failed-the-certificate-does-t3783.html#p7450). Log in to your Plesk / cPanel and change the SMTP server address to the host name like so:

[image]
[image]

Images copyrighted to the respective owner(s).

Comment: This "question" is both missing context and is not even a question. While you can use stackoverflow.com to create a question and also answer it yourself this should be done by first asking a question with a detailed problem description and then answering it by adding an actual answer (i.e. "Post your answer").  You currently put the answer part where the question belongs and completely miss the question part, i.e.  is not clear what question you are trying to answer.

Comment: And besides what Steffen said this does not seem on topic here as it is not related to programming in anyway.